# Reduce Memory Usage when Running Numpy Array Operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a fairly large `NumPy` array that I need to perform an operation on but when I do so, my ~2GB array requires ~30GB of RAM in order to perform the operation. I've read that `NumPy` can be fairly clumsy with memory usage but this seems excessive.

Does anyone know of an alternative way to apply these operations to limit the RAM load? Perhaps row-by-row/in place etc.?

Code below (ignore the meaningless calculation, in my code the coefficients vary):

```
import xarray as xr 
import numpy as np

def optimise(data):

    data_scaled_offset = (((data - 1000) * (1 / 1)) + 1).round(0)
    return data_scaled_offset.astype(np.uint16)

# This could also be float32 but I'm using uint16 here to reduce memory load for demo purposes
ds = np.random.randint(0, 12000, size=(40000,30000), dtype=np.uint16)

ds = optimise(ds) # Results in ~30GB RAM usage
```

Comment: I would try spliting it into multiple lesser arrays, optimise them one by one, and then concatante them.

Comment: Part of the reason your mem usage is increasing is because division, even it is by one, promotes your `np.uint16` (2 bytes per number) to `float64` (8 bytes per number)

Comment: This example is not really representative as most of it could be cancelled away. What's the **real operation** you're trying to do?

Comment: This is the real operation, the `data_scaled_offset` offset line results in a huge RAM usage. Yes the memory reduces when the variables are no longer in scope, but the spike in memory is what I want to reduce.

Comment: If that's the case, why don't you simplify it to `ds - 999` and by doing so get rid of all the intermediate arrays?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the coefficients in the calculation may be different, this was just an example. The memory issue persists with whatever numbers you choose.

Comment: Do you want the output dtype to be a `float` or a `uint16`?

Comment: `uint16` - The idea of the function is to convert an array from `float` to `uint16` using some arbitrary scale and offset values to minimise the size of the array for optimised file storage - but I've simplified it a lot here to make it easier to understand the issue - apologies if it is complicating things!

Comment: Right now you're passing an `uint16` array, but are getting back a `float` array, but you want the exact opposite? And why would rescaling an array make it more optimized for file storage?

Comment: I've updated the code - my code sometimes expects a `float32` but other times a `uint16` as the case is above (it depends on the input data I provide though the code currently handles both) - I'm optimising the data type to reduce file sizes. If I store the arrays in a native `float32` - the file size is double that of a `uint16` - this is fairly common with Earth Observation (satellite) data which I am using.

Comment: So why don't you start by explaining these rules? I.e. what is the input value range, what is the desired output, etc.

Comment: Because the example demonstrates the issue clearly and the two other contributors understand my issue just fine? I'm applying some mathematical operations to a `NumPy` array and getting a huge spike in memory usage - my question is how can I do the above example differently to reduce that? Adding extra information would be extraneous when the example code provided illustrates my issue?

Answer (score 3):

By default operations like multiplication, addition and many others... you can use numpy.multiply, numpy.add and use out parameter to use existing array for storing result. That will significantly reduce the memory usage. Please see the demo below and translate you code to use those functions instead

```py
arr = np.random.rand(100)
arr2 = np.random.rand(100)

arr3 = np.subtract(arr, 100, out=arr)
arr4 = arr+100
arr5 = np.add(arr, arr2, out=arr2)
arr6 = arr+arr2

print(arr is arr3) # True
print(arr is arr4) # False
print(arr2 is arr5) # True
print(arr2 is arr6) # False
```

Comment: This seems to work great, thank you - I'm just trying the other answer too to see which is best performing in terms of time etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could use eg. Numba or Cython to reduce memory usage.
Of course a simple Python loop would also be possible, but very slow.

**With allocated output array**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def optimise(data):
    data_scaled_offset=np.empty_like(data)
    # Inversely apply scale and scale and offset for this product
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            data_scaled_offset[i,j] = np.round_((((data[i,j] - 1000) *(1 / 1)) + 1),0)

    return data_scaled_offset
```

**In-Place**

```
@nb.njit()
def optimise_in_place(data):
    # Inversely apply scale and scale and offset for this product
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            data[i,j] = np.round_((((data[i,j] - 1000) *(1 / 1)) + 1),0)

    return data
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this works fine but the other method appears to be slightly faster and uses less memory from a quick analysis on a test array.