# Same Memory Usage for float 32 data and float 64 data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, out-of-memory

I have tried to use tracemalloc to trace the memory usage of my coding and I found that for float 32 data and float 64 data, they have same peak memory usage. Why?

Screenshot of output:

[image: Photo - Result]

float64:

```
import tracemalloc
import numpy as np
tracemalloc.start()
arr = np.zeros((100000000,), dtype=np.float64)
for i in range(100000000):
    arr[i] = i
current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
#current memory is the memory the code is currently using and 
#peak memory is the maximum space the program used while executing.
tracemalloc.stop()
print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")
```

Output:

```
Current memory usage is 800.14981MB; Peak was 800.160145MB
```

float32:

```
import tracemalloc
import numpy as np
tracemalloc.start()
arr = np.zeros((100000000,), dtype=np.float32)
arr = arr.astype(np.float32)
for i in range(100000000):
    arr[i] = i
current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
tracemalloc.stop()
print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")
```

Output:

```
Current memory usage is 400.149626MB; Peak was 800.149468MB
```

Comment: [python 3.x - Why does numpy.astype throw a memory error when the nparray size is below the memory limit? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557764/why-does-numpy-astype-throw-a-memory-error-when-the-nparray-size-is-below-the-me) ; [numpy - Python: memory error while changing data type from integer to float - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875222/python-) . Somewhat related: [python - Reduce Memory Usage when Running Numpy Array Operations - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078828)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the 2 snippets are not equivalent. There's this additional statement in the second snippet

```
arr = arr.astype(np.float32)
```

That statement (even though `arr` already have type `np.float32`):

- copies the array (which takes the same amount of memory as the old array)
- then assign the new array to `arr`,
- then discards the old array.

Therefore the peak memory doubles.